# Selenium finds the "next" button of web application but click() doesn't work

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

This is on a FF browser. 
I have a web application with a next button on a toolbar. My Selenium script finds the button and apparently clicks it as the element gets highlighted but the next page doesn't open.

How can I make it to go the the next page?

Here is an image of the toolbar in idle state:

[image]

And after the element is clicked:

[image]

As suggested in one other post I am clicking on a non-clickable element to get focus and then clicking the next button... but the button is highlighted but doesn't go to next page

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/span/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[11]/div")).click();
```

Part of the HTML is

```
<table id="ReportViewer1_fixedTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;">
<tbody>
  <tr style="background-color:#ECE9D8;">
  <tr id="ParametersRowReportViewer1" style="display:none;">
  <tr style="height:6px;font-size:2pt;display:none;">
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3">
   <span id="ReportViewer1_Toolbar">
    <div id="ReportViewer1_ctl06" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;border-bottom:1px #CCCCCC Solid;background-color:#ECE9D8;background-image:url(/PlateTechManager/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=BackImage&Version=10.0.30319.1&Color=%23ECE9D8&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.toolbar_bk.png);">
     <div style="padding-left:6px;">
      <div class=" " style="display:inline-block;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;vertical-align:top;">
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display:inline;">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td height="28px">
           <td width="4px"></td>
           <td height="28px">
           <td width="4px"></td>
           <td height="28px">
           <td width="4px"></td>
           <td height="28px">
           <td width="4px"></td>
           <td height="28px">
           <td width="4px"></td>
           <td height="28px">
             <div id="ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next">
              <div id="ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00" style="border: 1px solid transparent; background-color: transparent; cursor: default;">
               <table title="Next Page">
                 <tbody>
                   <tr>
                      <td>
```

I tried this and didn't work

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/span/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[11]/div"));
builder.moveToElement(we).click().build().perform();
```

**EDIT**
After looking some more into this behavior, it seems like the element is highlighted but not actually clicked.(How do I know this? When the test ends the element stays highlighted. As soon as I move the mouse the element becomes normal) So don't know why the click is not happening

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try:

- move to an element and click:

  ```
  Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
  builder.moveToElement(link).click(link).build().perform();
  ```
- click the link by executing javascript `click()`:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", link);
  ```

where `link` is a `WebElement` instance for the link (the result of `findElement()` call).

Comment: I tried this and didn't  work                                                                                Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/span/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[11]/div"));
    builder.moveToElement(we).click().build().perform();

Comment: @user3749141 any luck with the second approach? Thanks.